# Error adding a foreign key in Laravel 5.2 through migrations

Tags: sql, migration, laravel-5

I have two migrations as shown below:

2016_02_03_071404_create_company_users_table.php

```
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateCompanyUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('company_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies');
            $table->char('role', 20);
            $table->text('first_name');
            $table->text('last_name');
            $table->integer('age');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->text('password');
            $table->text('login_type');
            $table->string('phone_number')->unique();
            $table->integer('verified')->default(0);
            $table->text('profile_picture');
            $table->text('facebook_id');
            $table->text('twitter_id');
            $table->text('linkedIn_id');
            $table->text('google_plus_id');
            $table->text('current_location');
            $table->text('established_year');
            $table->text('device_type');
            $table->text('device_token');
            $table->text('device_model');
            $table->text('device_os_version');
            $table->text('last_login');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropifExists('company_users');
    }
}
```

2016_01_28_144808_create_jobs_table.php

```
<?php

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateJobsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->text('job_title');
            $table->text('job_description');
            $table->text('job_industry');
            $table->text('job_location');
            $table->integer('job_experience');
            $table->text('employment_type');
            $table->bigInteger('recruiter_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('recruiter_id')->references('id')->on('company_users');
            $table->tinyInteger('status')->default(1);
            $table->timestamp('posted_date')->default(Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString());
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropifExists('jobs');
    }
}
```

When I run `php artisan migrate` I get the following error:

[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `jobs` add constraint jobs_recruiter_id_foreign foreign
  key (`recruiter_id`) references `company_users` (`id`))

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... it was basically the order of execution of the migration files. So i changed the timestamps of the migration files to reorder the execution.... Works like charm.